# Manage code and errors in a json

Tags: php, json, php-5.3

I'am newbie in programming. I have a task when I need to send to a view a json as :

```
{
  "code"  : 200,
  "error" : 0,
  "data" : {
      "sLogo" : "http://test.com/images/logo.png",
      "aWinners": [
          {
           "sName": "name"
          }
       ]
   }
}
```

I now how to manage the data, but I don't understand how to manage `code` and `error`. Can you help me please to give some ideas ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english. The idea is that I need to send to the view this json but I don't understand what mus contain `code`

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about _`how to manage code and error`_

Comment: Are you using a framework? In that case which framework?

Comment: No, I don't use a specified famework, but this project is based on same components from symfony

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get values of code and error.

```
$json = '{"code"  : 200,"error" : 0,"data" : {"sLogo" : "http://test.com/images/logo.png","aWinners": [{"sName": "name"}]}}';
$arr = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo $arr['code'];
echo $arr['error'];
```

Comment: The idea is that I need to send this json to the view...But I don't understand what the `code` must contain

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: Just pass the json as string from controller to your view and then decode your data in the view as per your requirement.
In Controller
<?php
$json = '{"code"  : 200,"error" : 0,"data" : {"sLogo" : "http://test.com/images/logo.png","aWinners": [{"sName": "name"}]}}';
?>
In View
<?php
$arr = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$code= $arr['code'];
$error= $arr['error'];
?>
```